# How do you find the matrix representation of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having trouble with this problem. I have to find the matrix representation of a linear transformation. The example in my book got me my answer below but I do not feel that it is right/sufficient. Can someone explain matrix representation of a linear transformation?

Given $P_2(x)$ and $P_3(x)$ and the linear transformation: $L:P_2(x)\rightarrow P_3(x)$ defined by $L(p(x)) =  \displaystyle \int p(x)dx$. Find the matrix representation $A$ of the linear transformation $L$. Then find the rank of $A$ and the null space of $A$.

Here is what I have:
$$A =  \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\ 0&0&2\\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$R(A)$ = 2

$N(A)$ = 1

Comment: Do $P_2$ and $P_3$ have the same dimension? If not, then why is this matrix square? You should say what $P_2$ and $P_3$ are, also.

Comment: The indefinite integral is *indefinite*. What exactly is this mapping that takes polynomials of degree $\le 2$ to  polynomials of degree $\le 3$? Integral from where to where?

Comment: But indefinite integral is only defined up to a constant. How is it fixed in your definition ?

Comment: I thought $P_2$ had dim = 3 and $P_3$ had dim = 4????? That is what my notes say.

Comment: They do. A matrix would need to have $4$ rows.  Your matrix comes from a problem about the differentiation operator. Idea can be copied, matrix can't.

Comment: $P_3(x)$ is all polynomials with degree 3 or less and $P_2(x)$ is all polynomials with degree 2 or less.

Comment: That matrix $A$ looks more like the matrix of the derivation.

Comment: @jmendegan The following link may be useful. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64907/correspondences-between-linear-transformations-and-matrices/64911#64911

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a basis for the polynomial spaces, say $\{1,x,x^2\}$ and $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.  Then integration $\int_0^xp(t)dt$ takes the basis for $P_2$ to $x,x^2/2,x^3/3$.  In terms of vectors
$$
(1,0,0)\mapsto(0,1,0,0), \quad(0,1,0)\mapsto(0,0,1/2,0), \quad (0,0,1)\mapsto(0,0,0,1/3),
$$
so you get the matrix (w.r.t. these bases)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&1/2&0\\
0&0&1/3\\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: This is when you "normalize" $L$ imposing that $L(P)(0)=0$.

Comment: But where did you get the integration from 0 to x? Where does this come from?

Comment: @jmendegan i imposed it for the question to make sense

Comment: $L(0) = 0$ is forced upon you by linearity, isn't it? So this should be fine.

Comment: Can you explain the null space of this matrix?

Comment: the nullspace is 0

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @yoyo answer.

Mechanical way is:

$x  \mapsto y$
0: $(1,0,0)\mapsto(0,1,0,0)$
1: $(0,1,0)\mapsto(0,0,1/2,0)$
2: $(0,0,1)\mapsto(0,0,0,1/3)$
.
.
.
n: . . .

trannsformation required = $\displaystyle \sum\limits_0^n y^Tx$

Every $y^Tx$ will give you $4 \times 3$ matrix and you add them up.